# why it seems ajax request tax server more than standard http post?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I have a web application with much user accessed in the same time. that make our servers going so slow and heavy, because every user will upload pdf file or text from 10mb to 100mb per submit.
submitting with ajax request(file converted to dataurl) will make server more busy than i just upload use standard http post.
our server have 24GB ram and 18 core proccessor also iis 7 windows server 2008, when it at peak w3wp.exe will use 4gb memory and system idle 98% cpu. i see in task manager.

and also my application directed as sub application. (ex : http://10.888.127.78/subapp)

why is this happend?
and how to solve w3wp.exe and system idle use so much resource?

for now i just restart iis application when it going crazy again, but i need more solution than this.

thanks, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

System idle time is the time processor spends doing nothing, and that is not a problem.

As for the file upload, the problem could be the actual encoding of the file. You mention that the file is converted to dataurl in the Ajax request, which means the file is encoded to data URL format on upload, and decoded by the server back to binary form after upload. Data URL encoded files take more space than binary encoded files.

I don't know for sure, but I assume that your web server is receiving the complete data URL format data into memory first, before decoding it and saving it to disk. This part is taking memory.

So, I suggest that you look if it is possible to send the files without data URL encoding in the AJAX request. That should save some memory on the server.